# How to search in solr using different fields from different cores

Tags: solr

Using shards we can search in multiple cores as below

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/Core_2/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr/Core_2,localhost:8983/solr
  /Core_3&indent=true&q=Material_Number:"901751A/U" OR Material_type:"type1"
```

here i have called **Core_2** & **Core_3** where below are the fields available in both cores
**1. Material_Number** 
**2. Material_type**

is its possible to search with fields which are present in one of the cores 

EG.

```
  http://localhost:8983/solr/Core_2/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr/Core_2,localhost:8983/ 
    solr/Core_3&indent=true&q=Material_Number:"901751A/U" OR Material_type:"type1" OR
    field_of_Core_2:" search-text" OR field_of_Core_3:"search-text"
```

this throws me error,

From above eg. 
 **1. field_of_Core_2** is the field from **Core_2**
 **1. field_of_Core_3** is the field from **Core_3**

Comment: Will `field_of_Core_2` only exist on `Core_2`? Otherwise - no, not unless you have another field that tells you which core the document originates from.

Comment: Yes field_of_Core_2 exists only on Core_2. Sorry i has typed “if” instead of i“s”

Comment: What error message are you getting? As long as both fields are defined in your common schema, then it should work.

Comment: @MatsLindh Im getting undefined Field error 400, i am searching for 16 cores and their fields

Comment: can you please say what is that common schema, did you mean both fields should be defined in both cores of schemas or is there another method ? to define common schema

Comment: If you're going to use sharding to "group" together cores, the core you're querying must have a schema that is common for all the cores (otherwise it won't know that the fields exist in other cores). You can't combine them otherwise - the first core must know about all the fields that you're going to query across all cores.

Comment: You are great @MatsLindh, i was exactly looking for this can you please answer the common schema for the above example with the core name as Common_Core. This is indirectly querying for exact search in Solr i think so. and would be reference for others too. and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node you're searching against (i.e. the node that you're directing your query against) has to know about all the fields in both schemas - otherwise it'll give you an unknown field error message.

In your case the query should probably be made against a core named `Common_Core` or something similar, and that core must have a schema that has both `field_of_Core_2` and `field_of_Core_3` defined with their correct type.

You would then query that new, common core:

http://localhost:8983/solr/Common_Core/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr/Core_2,localhost:8983/solr/Core_3...

You can also define the shard selection parameter in a custom request handler, so that any query can just use `Common_Core` and `customRequestHandlerName` as it would any other core (i.e. `http://localhost:8983/solr/Common_Core/sharded` or something like that).

Comment: i understand Solr now better thanks, and what is maxScore ?. which is good higher or lower value ?

Comment: Neither. It's just a value indicating what the maximum score for a document in your query was. It's not comparable to anything useful except for other documents for the same query (and it does not map to a % value in any meaningful way). A document can be relevant or non-relevant both for a "high" and "low" value (which doesn't really make sense either, since you can boost a low score to always be a higher score, etc.), the only thing important is how it compares to other documents in the same result set for the same query (so comparing across queries isn't usually useful either).